# Unexpected $undefined with Nanoc and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, compilation, undefined, nanoc

I tried to reproduce this simple [tutorial](http://www.adriantomic.se/development/jquery-localscroll-tutorial/) about the script localScroll (jQuery). I used it and used the HTML code with Nanoc and it worked. Then, I tried to transform the HTML code in a HAML code.

[Here is the HAML code](http://pastebin.com/pKwT1b6d).

Now, when I'm trying to compile this code, I always have the same type of compilation error:

```
layout /default/:12: syntax error, unexpected $undefined   ...</script>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <div id='box-links'>\n  ...  layout /default/:12: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('  ... </head>\n  <body>\n    <div id='box-links'>\n      <a#{_ham...
```

[I let the full report here](http://pastebin.com/wDTDbF89).

I'm also giving you my js script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $('#box-links').localScroll({
           target:'body'
        });
});
```

As you can see, scripts are quite simple. I suppose that my error is not complicated but I don't find a solution.

Comment: Please try to properly format your questions. There is no need to use `<br>` for line breaks, and you can use the "Code Sample" button to format multi-line code.

Comment: May the comma after stylesheet in the first link causes it: `:rel => "stylesheet",`

Comment: @Colin: I'm sorry, I won't use <br> again and I'll use the "Code Sample" button next time

Comment: @regulus: Thank you, I changed and I put some commas. But I still have the same error

Comment: Put some commas? No I meant you should remove it.

Comment: My bad. I deleted them but I still have the same problem

Comment: Here is the last error report, if it can help ->
[link](http://pastebin.com/mNDZ9hfc)

Comment: I tried to correct the syntax.
Here is my first try: http://pastebin.com/T4wRUNmD
  And my second try is here: http://pastebin.com/DdGkmGcG
  For both tries, I don't have compilation errors but I know the syntax is not correct.
   And the problem is the same because the scroll function does not work at all.
I also put my Rules file if it can help: http://pastebin.com/yJA68wbt

Comment: Is the question so difficult? :s